# Value type is not bridged to Objective-C Error - Runtime error when using SKProductsRequest

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, storekit

I previously had been able to set up In-app purchases in a iOS app, however when coming back to the project and migrating to Swift 3 I am getting a run time error, there's no errors in the console but I am seeing

> Value type is not bridged to Objective-C Error

This is for the following function for when I request the products

```
//Request Products
func requestProductInfo() {

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

        let productIdentifiers = NSSet(array: productIDs)

        //ERROR
        let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)

        productRequest.delegate = self
        productRequest.start()

    }
    else {
        print("Cannot perform In App Purchases.")
    }

}
```

Does anyone understand what's going on ? I understand that there may be some issues using a Swift Array and Set with a NSSet but I have tried to change things around but still was getting errors.

```
var productIDs: Array<String?> = []
var productsArray = [SKProduct]()

func transactionAction() {
    let payment = SKPayment(product: self.productsArray[self.selectedProductIndex] as SKProduct)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    self.transactionInProgress = true

}

//Request Products
func requestProductInfo() {

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

        let productIdentifiers = NSSet(array: productIDs)
        let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)

        productRequest.delegate = self
        productRequest.start()

    }
    else {
        print("Cannot perform In App Purchases.")
    }

}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    if response.products.count != 0 {
      //  print("\(response.products.map {p -> String in return p.localizedTitle})")

        productsArray = response.products
    }
    else {
        print("There are no products.")
    }

    if response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count != 0 {
        print("\(response.invalidProductIdentifiers.description)")
    }

    print("Number of products in productsArray \(productsArray.count) - Number of products in productIDs \(productIDs.count)")

    setPurchaseButton()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried changing this line:

```
var productIDs: Array<String?> = []
```

to this?:

```
var productIDs: Array<String> = []
```

You may need to change some other parts according to this change, but with this you have no need to use risky `as!`:

```
        let productIdentifiers = Set(productIDs)
        let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
```

If you need to pass `Set<String>` to a method, you'd better not use intermediate `NSSet`. The worst new feature of Swift 3, *id-as-Any*, would make something disastrous.

Comment: Omg i can't believe I didn't see this, yeah it all works fine now; thanks !

Comment: @JSK, in older versions of Swift, passing a collection of Optionals to ObjC side caused compile time error. But with the new _id-as-Any_ feature, programmers need to be ultra-careful. The value types of ObjC collections are imported as `Any` into Swift side which consumes literally Any thing. What a type-safe language Swift has become... Take care and good luck for you and for your app.